# Rails3, respond_to to different places depending on where the user is coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have 2 different views/controllers etc. And so the user can create/modify (the same type) a record from two different places. Is it possible to make the page they're directed to different based on the page they're coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the referring page to determine where you want to redirect:

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
# or
request.referer
```

You can also add a hidden "source" text field to your different forms:

```
<input type='hidden' name='source' value='page1' />
<input type='hidden' name='source' value='page2' />
```

And then query params[:source] to determine which form the user submitted from.

Comment: The nice thing about using the hidden attribute is that even if you change the path of your other pages the redirect result will remain the same.